# Intuitive explanation of numpy.where?

Tags: python, numpy

I am learning machine learning and stumbled across this numpy.where statement in the textbook:

```
 housing["income_cat"] = np.ceil(housing["median_income"] / 1.5)
 housing["income_cat"].where(housing["income_cat"] < 5, 5.0, inplace=True)
```

Basically the code is dividing the median income to different categories and split them to separate categories (income_cat stands for income_category). What I don't understand though is how the .where should be interpreted:

I thought it goes: for values where `housing["income_cat"] <5`, then .. but then comes 5 in the second argument and `inplace= True` in the third argument.

Anybody can help me figure this out? Thanks!

Comment: Where the condition is not met, the values are replaced with 5.0. Inplace means wether to perform the operation in place on the data. See [`pandas.Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html)

Answer (score 0):

The `.where()` method [is defined](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html#pandas.Series.where) in the [Pandas Series class](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html).

In the call you reference, the first two arguments are positional and so they map to the `cond` and `other` variables. The `other` value is usd when the condition `cond` evaluates to False.

As an example:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> column = pd.Series(data=(1,2,3))
>>> column.where(column > 2, -1)
0   -1
1   -1
2    3
dtype: int64
```

The condition `column > 2` evaluates to False for the first two elements of this Series. There, it gets replaced by -1.

The `inplace=True` setting ensures that the operation does not return a new object, but changes the object inplace, which is a consideration of performance, but has the downside of traceability.